# Free Software GIS mobile data collection software for Wildlife conservation?

Tags: open-source, mobile, gis

Looking for Free Software GIS mobile data collection software for Wildlife conservation. The idea is to use a mobile touch screen device with satellite navigation to keep track of objects such as nesting boxes and feeding stations for birds. Nesting boxes should be cleaned annually and the result (what kind of nest the box contained) should be recorded together with the current time. Feeding stations should be refilled often during winter and the amount filled should be recorded together with the current time.

If the device is within some distance of a previously recorded object, the software should show a table where the attributes of the object can be edited and sub objects can be created and edited. A sub object is fore example a cleaning/refilling.

Otherwise the software should show a map and a button to record a new object at the current location.

Mobile syncing and caching could be nice, but not necessary. Keeping all the data on the mobile device and syncing directly to a computer occasionally would be good enough. Likewise, having photos taken with a built in camera automatically be associated with the currently active object would be nice, but not necessary. Obviously, the interface should be simple and require as few touches as possible to get the job done.

Has anyone done this? Which Free Software would be the closest match to start from? (I have used PostgreSQL, but never for anything mobile or interacting with a satellite navigation device.)

Comment: Speaking of mobile: which OS is acceptable? Android, iOS, WM, Tizen …?